# Toasts in Android

Tags: android, android-toast

I've been working with few widgets but when i run the following `Activity` nothing happens.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button bt =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What do you expect to happen that isn't happening?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get Activity context so replace this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with this:

```
Toast.makeText(NameOfYourActivity.this, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Note that you need to change `NameOfYourActivity.this` to have the name of your activity, which isn't shown in your code snippet.

**EDIT**

You can also use only `this` instead of `NameOfYourActivity.this` if you are creating toast directly inside Activity context and not in others (e.g. `OnClickListener` context)

If you are in fragment use `getActivity()` instead of `NameOfYourActivity.this`

**EDIT 2**

To complete the answer I'll add also the case in which you need to obtain context in classes that don't extend `Activity` or `Fragment` (e.g. `BaseAdapter` or model classes).

In this case you have to pass context via constructor and use it as global variable. NEVER use a static context if not needed.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Context context;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void showToastFromHere() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Method in MyClass.class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and you call the method in your activity creating an instance of that class:

```
MyClass toastClass = new MyClass(NameOfYourActivity.this);
toastClass.showToastFromHere();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I think you have to use your app context to show Toast, make intents, etc.

Comment: Activity Context is better for those things

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: what would happen if the OP is extending Activity and not Fragment ?

Comment: getActivity() still works in that case. The fragment has to be hosted by some Activity

Comment: Tech, I believe the point was that no one said anything about a Fragment so how do you know they are even being used? But I don't want to speak for @Blackbelt